# How to assign a value to class member from another form in C#?

Tags: c#, class, object, oop

I have 2 form .First one is Form1 and the second is Form2. And also i have a class in Form1 which name is Matrix.

```
public class Matris
    {
        public int city;
       public int country;


    };
```

I want to reach the class member from Form2 and assign a value them. But when i create an object from form1 and try to reach them i cant see the Matris member.
im creating an object in form2 like this. But i cant see the class or members.
Form1 f1=new Form1();

How can i do that? is it possible, thanks for your help.

Comment: Defining a class within another class does not make it a "member". You would need a field or property.

Comment: Better way imho, is to separate class in separate file, and then create object , with properties and fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define property of field of `Matris` in `Form` class and then you can use this variable in `Form`
objects:

```
public class Form
{
    public Matris Matris { get; set; }
}

public class Matris
{
    public int city;
    public int country;
}
```

And you can use:

```
Form form = new Form() { Matris = new Matris { City = 1 } };
Form form2 = new Form() { Matris = new Matris { City = 2 } };
```

or if you want to assign `form.Matris` to `form2.Matris`:

```
form2.Matris = form.Matris;
```

As a good practice, it is better to separate class in a separate files.